# Show that if $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, then $[a+b]\ge [a]+[b]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

How does one go about proving this? I know for instance that for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, then $x-1< [x]\le x$ (where $[x]$ denotes "the greatest integer in x"), so I feel compelled to use this on $a$ and $b$, that is

1. $a-1< [a]\le a$
2. $b-1<[b]\le b$
3. $a+b-1<[a+b]\le a+b$

Comment: Is $[x]$ intended to be the ceiling function here?

Comment: It denotes "the greatest integer in x". That is, the greatest integer less than or equal to x

Comment: So, the floor function then. If you think about the fractional parts of a and b, then they either add up to less than 1 or $\ge$ 1. In either case, your desired result holds. The intuition is that rounding down cannot make sums larger.

Answer (score 1):

$$[a+b]-([a]+[b])=[([a]+\{a\}) + ([b]+\{b\})] - [a]-[b]\\
=[a]+[b]+[\{a\}+\{b\}]-[a]-[b]  = [\{a\}+\{b\}] \ge [0]=0$$
where $\{x\} = x - [x] \in [0,1)$.

Comment: How can you take out $[a]$ and $[b]$ at the second step (the second $=$ sign)? How did you get $[([a]+\{a\})+([b]+\{b\})]-[a]-[b]=[a]+[b]+[\{a\}+\{b\}]-[a]-[b]$?

Comment: E.g.,  [3.4+1.7]=3+1+[0.4+0.7].

Comment: Taking the floor of the sum of an integer and another number is the same as taking the sum of the integer and the floor of the other number.